# How can I use special characters in my username?

Tags: zombsroyale.io

I want my nickname to be `<KyleKiller>`, but it doesn't work. I seems I can't use the greater-than symbol and the less-than symbol. How can I use these characters in my nickname?

Comment: My assumption is that you can't, and you'll just have to settle for a name that excludes those symbols, but you may be able to use `&lt;KyleKiller&gt;`, if the game handles HTML encoded symbols like that.

Comment: Can somebody explain to me why this post is receiving downvotes? It seems like a valid question to me

Comment: Many games prohibit HTML symbols as a precaution against someone trying to mess with their system.

Answer (score -1):

On PC, you can't use greater/less than symbols, but you can use others like  `^_^`